# Elasticsearch-logging rc and svc are getting automatically deleted

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/fluentd-elasticsearch

The cluster is getting automatically deleted by using these configs to create the cluster.

From https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/11435 the solution is to remove

> kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"

Though without these the elasticsearch is not available through the kubernetes master.

Should i create a pull request to remove the line from the files in the repo so people dont get confused?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to remove this line from the yaml file in the repository because the default kubernetes cluster setup script uses these files to start the cluster addons. I do think we need better documentation, as pointed out in the [original issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/11435). Is there any problem letting kubernetes start the addons for you?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend making Elasticsearch a normal Kubernetes Service. You can expose in one of the following ways:

1. Set service.Type = NodePort and access it via any public ip of node:nodePort
2. Set service.Type = LoadBalancer, this will only work on cloud providers that have loadbalancers
3. Expose the RC directly through a host port (not recommended)

Those are just the common options for accessing a Service, please see the following thread for a more detailed discussion: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kubernetes-sig-network/B-A_RuqpFWk

It's generally *not* a good idead to send all external traffic meant for a Kubernetes service through the apiserver. However if you must do so, you can via an endpoint such as:

> /api/v1/proxy/namespaces/default/services/nginx:80/

Where default is the namespace, nginx is the name of your service and 80 is the service port (needed to disambiguate multiport services).

Comment: I dont seem to be able to reach my elasticsearch-logging service by these urls: https://kubernetesmaster/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/elasticsearch-logging/ or https://kubernetesmaster/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/elasticsearch-logging:9200/. Is this because kube-system is a protected namespace?

Comment: 503: message": "no endpoints available for service \"elasticsearch-logging\"". So it doesnt find a suitable endpoint. The LB has both a local IP and a public IP. $ kubectl get endpoints --namespace=kube-system shows: elasticsearch-logging     10.204.0.11:9200

Comment: I found out how this works. The port description has a name, not a number. This works: https://kubernetesmaster/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/elasticsearch-logging:http/ where http is defined in the service name for port.

Comment: Yep, named ports are a thing but you don't *have* to name your ports.